# Ember-CLI: Ember Build keeps building the wrong index.html

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Ideally, I want my index.html from this:

```
<!-- app/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Program With Erik Blog Example</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    {{content-for 'head'}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/example1.css">

    {{content-for 'head-footer'}}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{content-for 'body'}}

    <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/example1.js"></script>

    {{content-for 'body-footer'}}
  </body>
</html>
```

into production code. But for some strange reason, each time I call ember build, I do not get the expected production-looking code. Instead I get something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>
    .
    .
    .
    <!-- lots of code -->
```

It's the default firebase page!

[image: Firebase welcome page]

What is happening? I've deleted the picture multiple times. But each time I call ember build it builds the firebase default page rather than my ember app index.html.

I'm new to ember and I've been fiddling around heavily with the config/environment.js and the firebase.js. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: In the public directory of your ember app, do you have a file `index.html`

Comment: Yes! I do have a file there and it is the same HTML file that keeps getting built!

Comment: I think that fixed it too. If you post an answer I will give you best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On initialising a firebase app, one is prompted:

```
? What do you want to use as your public directory? (public)
```

make sure to set the `dist` folder as the public directory, that is

```
? What do you want to use as your public directory? (public) dist
```

using the default `public` will cause the above behavior no matter how many times you build your Ember app. 
To fix the problem, re-initialise the firebase app with the `firebase init` command, and set the right folder as the public directory.